# How to do horizontal lines from a one column file using gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

Having a file with just one column of data like for example:

10

2

34

4.5

16

I'd like to plot a stack of horizontal lines as plotting a horizontal line from let's say -3 to 3 (x range) for a y value equal to the first row (10 in the example), then replot a another horizontal line ranging from x=[-3:3] with a y value equal to the second row (2 in the example), and so on.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

Use the `vectors` plotting style.

```
plot "file" using (-3):($1):(6):(0) with vectors nohead
```

The four values in the `using` expression are `x` (plain number -3), `y` (value from first column), `dx` and `dy`.