# Plotting 1D data as constant functions in 2D plot with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a 2D plot and want to draw horizontal straight lines from a given data file, so that each data point of the file is represented as a horizontal straight line in the existing 2D plot.

**My approach so far:**

I've tried using the `for` command, but I don't know how to write the current data point into a formular like x = C where C is the value of the data point:

```
for [i=1:10] "data.dat" u 2 every ::i::i
```

... is not what I meant.

```
for [i=1:10] x = "data.dat" u 2 every ::i::i
```

... is not a valid gnuplot command.

And furthermore, the range of `i` is variable, so that is another problem I have to solve with this approach.

**Using arrows:**

Like this posts suggests: [Adding Horizontal lines on 2D plot with gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079273/adding-horizontal-lines-on-2d-plot-with-gnuplot). But in that example the author didn't need to draw the lines from a data file.

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39459029/how-to-do-horizontal-lines-from-a-one-column-file-using-gnuplot

Comment: Thank you for this link! I honestly couldn’t find it.